# Inbox is not working

Tags: bug, status-completed

The inbox displays the new items notification, but when I click on it, it comes up completely blank, without showing the old items either. Was working fine yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We made some emergency changes to the network on Sunday; this should resolve itself soon.